# Index notation interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I'm having some confusion with index notation and how it works with contravariance/covariance.

$(v_{new})^i=\frac{\partial (x_{new})^i}{\partial (x_{old})^j}(v_{old})^j$

$(v_{new})^i=J^i_{\  j}(v_{old})^j$

$(v_{new})_i=\frac{\partial (x_{old})^j}{\partial (x_{new})^i}(v_{old})_j$

$(v_{new})_i=(J^{-1})^j_{\  i}(v_{old})_j$

So these are the standard rules for transforming contra and covariant vectors.
Now if we want to convert this into a matrix equation is there an exact set of rules with regards index position?

For example for the covariant transformation I can transpose the matrix which swaps the index order(Not sure how this makes sense) and this gives the right answer if we treat the covariant vectors as columns.

Or I can move the  $(v_{old})_j$ to the right of the J inverse and treat it as a row vector and this gives the right answer and I don't need to even consider what a transpose is in this interpretation.

Now both of these interpretations give the correct answers but they seem to have different meanings for upper vs lower and horizontal order.

Is there a best way to think about this, which way makes the most sense in terms of raising/lowering with metric tensors and transforming higher order tensors?

Comment: do you recognize that the $j$ index indicates a summation in the LHS of your formulas?

Comment: I don't know exactly what part you're having trouble with but here's how these formulas relate to vectors in the $2\times 2$ case: $$v^i = M^i_jw^j \iff \pmatrix{v^1 \\ v^2} = \pmatrix{M^1_1 & M^1_2 \\ M^2_1 & M^2_2}\pmatrix{w^1 \\ w^2} \\ v_i = M^j_iw_j = w_jM^j_i \iff \pmatrix{v_1 & v_2} = \pmatrix{w_1 & w_2}\pmatrix{M^1_1 & M^1_2 \\ M^2_1 & M^2_2}$$ Notice that while in index notation it doesn't really matter the order of the factors, if we want to convert to matrix form we should have the lower summing index on the left factor and the upper one on the right.